# 8 bit accumulator in verilog, output data type

Tags: verilog

Here is my verilog code, and I keep getting the error where I have to connect my outputs(s and carry) to structural net expression. Here's the code:

```
module p2(SW,KEY0,KEY1,LEDR,HEX0,HEX1,HEX2);
 input [7:0] SW;
 input [7:0] LEDR;
 input KEY1,KEY0;

 output[6:0] HEX0,HEX1,HEX2;

 reg[7:0] s;
 reg carry;

 accumulator acm (SW[7:0],s,carry,KEY0,KEY1);

endmodule 

module accumulator (A, accum,overflow, clk, clr);

 input [7:0] A;
 input clk, clr;
 output [7:0] accum;
 output reg overflow;

 reg [7:0] accum;

 always@(clk) begin
    if(clk) begin
        {overflow,accum} <= accum + A;
    end
    else if(~clr) begin
        accum = 8'b00000000;
    end
end

endmodule
```

Comment: Can you show the top module code ?!

Comment: Hi, that's all the codes I have. top module code is p2

Comment: Oh, ok. So you're missing the HEX0, HEX1, HEX2 output. They must connect to something. (I'm a newbie on Verilog too, but I think that everything must be wired to something).

Comment: Please paste in the actual error. Right now your description of the problem is a little vague (ie: which output is it complaining about?)

Comment: We are not required nor not taught of using testbench, we usually use modelsim or test it on the board

Comment: @aladdin, learn how to make a basic testbench and run Verilog simulations to generate a waveform (.vcd). There are good/free Verilog/SystemVerilog simulators available, even some that run on the cloud for free. FPGA will never be able show you where something went wrong, simulators can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your compiler probably says something like:

> output or inout port "accum"/"overflow" must be connected to a structural net expression

which means that both `s` and `carry` should be define as wires, not regs.

Btw I would recommend you to change `accumulator` code a little bit:

```
always@(posedge clk or negedge clr) begin
    if(~clr) begin
        accum <= 'b0;
        overflow <= 'b0;
    end else begin
        {overflow,accum} <= accum + A;
    end
end
```

---

@Filipe: it's possible to define an output port that has no driver. But in that case (like here), all the logic might be synthesized away, because there will be no output depending on each input signal.

Comment: but i need add it up onto S, and I cannot do that with a wire

Comment: p2 is the main module , it passes in the values and later display it

Comment: Thanks for the enlightenment, like I've said, still newbie and learning.

Comment: @Qiu, Hope you don't mind but I improved the code to your `accumulator` recommendation. `overflow` also needed an asynchronous reset. Asynchronous resets should use non-blocking (`<=`) assignments.

Comment: @Greg: not at all, since you are right. I don't how I could miss that.